# Auditing of Shell commands executed via kubectl exec

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to log individual shell commands executed after login to pod via kubectl exec? If auditing shell commands is possible, how to configure kubernetes auditing for that?

Comment: Your question is too abroad for a single post, please read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and correct it.

Comment: Edited the question to make it crisp. Can someone take this question?

Comment: Your question is still hard to answer because it's not going in the direction of best practices. Usually logs are for system events/errors, in order to monitor a shell you'd have to configure like you would configure a linux for that. But this does not apply to every case. Add to the question your **current state** and what you **plan to achieve**.